# What is the purpose of a zoo file in machine learning/openVino code

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network, openvino

I am trying to run the following code:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/classification.cpp

I found all of the pre-trained models here: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2019_R1/_docs_Pre_Trained_Models.html

However, I only see the xml files.

What exactly are the zoo files needed in the lines of code below, what are they used for, and where do I find them?

I understand the help string for the source code says zoo files are optional

```
const std::string modelName = parser.get<String>("@alias");
const std::string zooFile = parser.get<String>("zoo");

keys += genPreprocArguments(modelName, zooFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

**@alias** contain alias name of model to extract preprocessing parameters from models.yml file and the **zoo** file is actually related with models.yml where it contain optional path to file with preprocessing parameters.

you should be able to find the models.yml file in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/dnn

If you had installed Openvino Toolkit, you should have the folder:
C:\Program Files(x56)\IntelSWTools\openvino\deployment_tools\tools\model_downloader

once in that dir, type in you cmd or terminal: python downloader.py --print_all

it will list all models that are supported & use the command: python downloader.py (name of model that you want) -o (specify path that you want to store the model)

you should have all of the required files of the model after successfully downloaded it

Thanks and have a great day ahead!